# Function guards & 'where' syntax in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, syntax, where-clause, guard

I am trying to Learn Me a Haskell, and I decided to practice by writing a simple function for inverting 3x3 matrices.  It should be easy, yet nothing I try will compile successfully.

Here is my code:

```
matInv3x3 :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]]
matInv3x3 m
    | length m /= 3         = error "wrong number of rows"
    | length (m !! 0) /= 3  = error "wrong number of elements in row 0"
    | length (m !! 1) /= 3  = error "wrong number of elements in row 1"
    | length (m !! 2) /= 3  = error "wrong number of elements in row 2"
    | det == 0              = error "zero determinant"
    | otherwise = mInv
    where   a = m !! 0 !! 0
            b = m !! 0 !! 1
            c = m !! 0 !! 2
            d = m !! 1 !! 0
            e = m !! 1 !! 1
            f = m !! 1 !! 2
            g = m !! 2 !! 0
            h = m !! 2 !! 1
            i = m !! 2 !! 2
            det = a*(e*i - f*h) - b*(i*d - f*g) + c*(d*h - e*g)
            A = (e*i - f*h) / det
            B = -(d*i - f*g) / det
            C = (d*h - e*g) / det
            D = -(b*i - c*h) / det
            E = (a*i - c*g) / det
            F = -(a*h - b*g) / det
            G = (b*f - c*e) / det
            H = -(a*f - c*d) / det
            I = (a*e - b*d) / det
            mInv = [[A,B,C],[D,E,F],[G,H,I]]
```

I am trying to guard against everything which can go wrong: bad list dimensions, and zero determinant.  I modeled it after examples in the 'Learn You A...' book.  I am trying to rely on the lazy evaluation in case the matrix has zero determinant.

GHCi won't compile it, citing a parse error for the '=' on line 10 (where b is defined).  I'm sure there is some simple, fundamental thing I am missing.  Can someone point out what I did wrong?

UPDATE:

I implemented the fixes proposed in the comments, and also corrected the swapped indices mistake I made (didn't spot it before, as the code wouldn't compile).  Here is the fixed code, which inverts 3x3 matrices correctly:

```
matInv3x3 :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]]
matInv3x3 m
    | length m /= 3         = error "wrong number of rows"
    | length (m !! 0) /= 3  = error "wrong number of elements in row 0"
    | length (m !! 1) /= 3  = error "wrong number of elements in row 1"
    | length (m !! 2) /= 3  = error "wrong number of elements in row 2"
    | abs det < 1.0e-15     = error "zero or near-zero determinant"
    | otherwise = mInv
    where   [[a,d,g],[b,e,h],[c,f,i]] = m
            det = a*(e*i - f*h) - b*(i*d - f*g) + c*(d*h - e*g)
            a' = (e*i - f*h) / det
            b' = -(d*i - f*g) / det
            c' = (d*h - e*g) / det
            d' = -(b*i - c*h) / det
            e' = (a*i - c*g) / det
            f' = -(a*h - b*g) / det
            g' = (b*f - c*e) / det
            h' = -(a*f - c*d) / det
            i' = (a*e - b*d) / det
            mInv = [[a',b',c'],[d',e',f'],[g',h',i']]
```

Comment: There is no error on the line you mentioned when I compile it - perhaps your indentation in your editor is different than here? On another note, you can't give variables names starting with capital letters - `A`,`B` .. `I` - are all invalid. You can do `_A`.

Comment: Haskell is white-space sensitive. The `where` clause looks suspicious to me, I'd put it in at least three more spaces to be sure.

Comment: I had a 'tab' instead of four spaces which was screwing it up invisibly.  I fixed that, and also used _A as you suggested.  Now the function works as expected.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The conventional names for those values would be `a'` through `i'`. GHC treats values starting with `_` specially - it doesn't warn if they're unused.  I wouldn't recommend that naming.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  I'd better learn good habits early.

Comment: you can assign all matrix elements in single line `[[a,d,g],[b,e,h],[c,f,i]] = m`

Comment: It is not safe to compare doubles for equality as in `det == 0`. please see this [link](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

Comment: I tried a test case in which det == 0 was detected correctly by the guard.  Are there really cases for which det == 0 isn't triggered, yet division by the determinant would still fail?

Comment: @user2790167, no, not fail, but give very poor results.  Often floating point arithmetic will give very small values when it should give 0 (i.e. when the matrix was not actually invertible), and then the inverse of the matrix will be some nonsense with giant numbers, which doesn't actually multiply with the original to give the identity.

Comment: I see your point, but I think it's an acceptable inflexibility.  A matrix would have to be very badly-conditioned for double-precision arithmetic to give significant errors.  How could this be avoided without using fractional number types?

Comment: @user2790167 Check `abs det < epsilon` for some really very small constant `epsilon`.

Comment: @user2790167 Could you put your answer in the answer box, instead of in the question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good exercise would be to generalize this function to arbitrary nxn matrices. Here is one way to calculate the determinant of an nxn as a start in case you are interested.

```
-- Remove the nth element from a list
remove :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
remove n xs = ys ++ (tail zs)
  where
    (ys, zs) = splitAt n xs

-- Minor matrix of cofactor C(i,j)
minor :: Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
minor i j xs = remove j $ map (remove i) xs

-- The determinant of a square matrix represented as a list of lists
-- representing column vectors, that is [column].
det :: Num a => [[a]] -> a
det (a:[]) = head a
det m = sum [(-1)^i * (c1 !! i) * det (minor i 0 m) | i <- [0 .. (n-1)]]
  where
    c1 = head m
    n = length m
```